Does this solve the static initialization order fiasco?
Let's just say a static variable, a vector that has stuff added to it automatically at program startup. This is problematic because at any point push_back might be called on that vector before the vector is initialised:
inline std::vector<const char*> my_vector;

int register_type(const char* name)
{
    static int id_counter = 0;
    my_vector.push_back(name);
    return id_counter++;
}

inline int my_type_1 = register_type("my_type_1");
Although technically this will be fine, because inline static variables are guaranteed according to the standard to be initialised in their order of appearance, it's probably a bad idea generally, not least because that assurance isn't given if I call register type from another header or cpp file. So I thought what if I turn the vector into a pointer to a vector that is initialised if it hasn't been yet:
    static inline std::unique_ptr<std::vector<const char*>> p_to_types;
    
    int register_type(const char* name)
    {
        static bool bHasBeenInitialised = false;
        static int id_counter = 0;
    
        if (!bHasBeenInitialised)
        {
            p_to_types = std::make_unique<std::vector<const char*>>();
            bHasBeenInitialised = true; 
        }   
        p_to_types->push_back(name);
    
        return id_counter++;
    }
    
    inline int my_type_1 = register_type("my_type_1");

Now the vector will be initialised before it's first use, which is what we want. However the program still has instructions to initialise the unique_pointer, which, if it happens after I've initialised the vector, will erase the pointer address with null when it constructs the unique_ptr, correct? So this doesn't solve the problem.
I know the common approach is to place vector as a static variable inside a function, but then this results in a branch each time the vector is accessed, to check whether it's been initialised.

Make them Singleton and control the init in program startup? At least you may control the initialization order. I don't think  int my_type_1 needs to be inline. If could be a member variable in singleton.

Your title asks if you have solved the static order initialisation fiasco and then the text of the question demonstrates that you haven't. So I'm not really sure what you are asking here.

"place vector as a static variable inside a function, but then this results in a branch each time the vector is accessed, to check whether it's been initialised." what branch you meant? Maybe a snippet for it.

Just might want to check out the nifty counter idiom which is another way to solve the static initialisation order fiasco.

I wouldn't worry about the "cost of a branch" of the common solution you mention. You are already doing memory-allocations, which will drown out any additional overhead. So a fraction of a nanosecond (if the difference is even measurable) doesn't justify the abomination of your second example.

@Juliean The dynamic memory allocation for the vector only happens once. The check to see if the vector has been initialised in the idiomatic way, ie., static function-local variable occurs every single time it's accessed.

@Zebrafish push_back allocated every time the function is called? Or are you talking about runtime access later down the line? In any way, the difference will surely not be measureable. Did you benchmark it or are you just trying to prematurely micro-optimize here? Still, you could always create a another global "vector&" from the function that you can access in parts of the code where you know that the initialization-stage has been completed.

I've read that all you need to do is put access to the static resource behind a function call. Is that not correct? All this talk of singletons and other patterns seems excessive with what I've read about the static initialization order fiasco.

@sweenish Aren't they the same thing? static variable inside a function and singleton?

Your code has an explicit branch around an explicit static boolean variable and a dynamic allocation, and it doesn't solve the problem. The Meyers's singleton has (in a usual implementation) a hidden branch around a hidden static boolean variable and no dynamic allocation, and it works.

There is basically only one sure fire way to avoid SIOF, avoid global variables, singletons and switch to dependency injection. Another way is to have on TU with a meyer's singelton and make sure it does NOT depend on any other static variables.

@n.m.couldbeanAI That comes at a cost of a branch each time it's accessed in your code, whereas with some extra work you can eliminate that. If you can ensure the correct initialisation order before entering main and initialise the variable correctly, then you can access that variable as a global variable, not a function-local static, which as I said branches each time it's accessed.

You can but you don't want to. Meyers's singleton is plenty good enough. If you need to shave every possible nanosecond off your initialization code, you better redesign it completely such that it is not scattered between multiple source files.

@Zebrafish To me singleton means more than just a (usually free) function for a static getter. Perhaps I'm splitting hairs. You're right that the intent is the same.

you may define a lazy static singleton in anothor cpp file
std::vector<const char*>& getMyVector() {
  static std::vector<const char*> vec;
  return vec;
}

and use getMyVector() in your register function
int register_type(const char* name)
{
    static int id_counter = 0;
    getMyVector().push_back(name);
    return id_counter++;
}


Yes, this is the idiomatic way. In this way every time you call getMyVector there's a branch to check if static std::vector has been initialised yet. I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid this.

Note that this might result in kicking the ball down the curb as the point at which the object goes out of scope is now fuzzy. If you have no code that executes after main exits, you're safe, but I've seen code that shoots itself in the foot by assuming the lazy initialized logger will still be alive when some global object's destructor runs.

should be fine because that jump would not be executed after init and it will produce stable branch predict success. you can also try gcc/clang's init_priority as a last resort inline std::vector<const char*> __attribute__ ((init_priority (2000))) my_vec

@Zebrafish The idiomatic way is to NOT  have singletons at all. They are killing for unit testability. Just use dependency injection e.g. create instance of global state in main and pass interfaces (with getters) to the pieces of code that need that information.

@PepijnKramer Haha, that's not really idiomatic, sure maybe in Rust that's what you're forced to do.

No it really is once your software gets up to a certain level of complexity. Globals and singletons invariably lead to reference semantics and that is just not maintainable in the long run and lead to "spooky action at a distance". See Value Semantics: Safety, Independence, Projection, & Future of Programming - Dave Abrahams CppCon 22.  And yes for smaller (embedded system it might be idiomatic now or a design tradeoff to use singletons but still...). Note I do not say you need dynamic polymorphism for dependency injection ;)

@Zebrafish I, as one who support long-running project where someone went overly singleton-y, along with Qt and threads without using thread pool - Singletons are becoming a nightmare to handle when we exit the app. Especially that that have to handle it in completely differet ways if you exit Windows app, if that's Linux app and if that's exit caused by linux singal system

that's why Google style guide strongly recommend not to use static variables unless it's constinit.

Bah. Google stole that bit of advice from me. I should sue. But then I'm opening myself up to lawsuits from whoever I stole the bit of advice from.
